# How to fix sound playing over itself in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game and I want my character to have footsteps. The issue is my footsteps sound keep playing overitself and causes my game to lag bad

Here is a snippet of what is happeing

```
if direction == 'right':
        self.up = False
        self.down = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = True

        if self.x == 250:
            if level.x > -500:
                level.x -= self.speed
        if level.x <= -500 or self.x < 250:
            self.x += self.speed
        if self.x >= 484:
            self.x = 484

        playSound = True


    if playSound:
        footSteps.play(-1)
        playSound = False

    if direction != 'right' and direction != 'left' and direction != 'up' and direction != 'down':
        playSound = False
        footStep.stop()
```

Comment: Playing sound should not lag your game if you play sound concurrently with game play.  You should basically never wait for anything to completion, but rather, check during every pass of the game loop whether an event has completed or not.  You need to rethink your sound playing flags and methods to be more along the lines of: needed, start, stop, active.

Answer (score 0):

For a sound you just play the sound, -1 is for music to loop it:

```
pew = pygame.mixer.Sound("YOUR PEW SOUND FILE HERE")
pew.play()
```

Comment: I made the changes but the issue is still there